# Import product from xml to drupal commerce (Drupal 10)

Tags: drupal-commerce, drupal-feeds, drupal-10

I have a problem when importing a product price from an xml file.
I want to import a product using feeds and I use commerce_feeds
I get the product name, but when I get the price I get an error:
**The options "availableCurrencies" do not exist in constraint "Drupal\field_validation\Plugin\Validation\Constraint\CurrencyConstraint".**

I can't find a solution online. Maybe someone knows the solution to this problem.
I want to do it on Drupal 10. Where exactly, where and what do I need to add?

I tried adding the array

```
availableCurrencies = ['USD', 'EUR'];
```

in different places. Unsuccessfully.